# Get id aswell as page name using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have an htaccess file where i rewrite
*domain.com/index.php?page=home* to *domain.com/home*

My entire htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I'm attempting to do is also get the &id= from the url so *index.php?page=home&id=5* would be rewritten to */home/5*.

And another issue I'm experiencing is that I can not open files in other directories like for-example the images directory. When i open the images directory i get the 404 page i have set for the site because it is not a page and it is trying to read *images/imagefile.jpg* as a page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this before the first condition:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Regarding images opening as pages, that should not be the case - your `.htaccess` conditions prevent that from happening. You need to be sure that the file you are requesting exists in the images directory - if it does not, the request will be forwarded to `index.php`. Also make sure that there are no other `.htaccess` files interfering - though I doubt this is the case for you.

It could be that you are referencing your images relative to the current request. So, for example, if you have `<img src="images/something.png>` and the current page is `/services/something`, it will try to request `/services/images/something`, which is not what you want.

To solve this, either add a trailing slash to the `img` tag (`<img src="/images/something.png>`) or set the `base` tag accordingly (`<base href="/">`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added this before the first condition but the same thing happends. When i go to domain.com/home/5 i get sent to the 404 error page. However domain.com/home&id=5 works just as i want it.